# Why is iTunes not shuffling songs but albums?

Tags: itunes, macos

I am currently running iTunes 12.0.1.26 on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), and every time I try to play any set of songs randomly the songs get grouped by album. I have had this problem with previous versions of iTunes running on OS X Maverick. I would like to be able to shuffle the songs individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls → Shuffle → Choose your preference.

Screenshot:

[image]